# user privilege to create schedule jobs Centos

Tags: linux, centos

In my Centos Linux class i had a task that says:

Create user named X user and give this user privilege to create schedule jobs (Scheduling one-time tasks && scheduling recurring tasks.

But far as i know, by default any user can schedule jobs.

So my question is:
Can I (as a root user) control creating scheduled jobs privileges for any user ? if so how and when it is useful to do so ?

Comment: Easy google search reveals:  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restrict-at-cron-command-to-authorized-users/

Comment: Thanks for the link !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root can control which user can use `cron` or `at` via `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny`. If you have first file for the users not in the file usage of cron is denied. For second file is vise-versa.

The use case can be: corporate environment, Most of the users do not need to do any `cron` or `at` activities. Only short list of functional users may need this.

Comment: Thanks for the help.It appeared that Linux have **/etc/cron.deny** and **/etc/at.deny** files empty by default which gives all users the privilege to use **crontab** and **at**.
So, I had to rm these two files and touch **/etc/crop.allow** and **/etc/at.allow** and enter the user’s names who can use the **crontab** and **at** each in a separate row, in this way no one but those users and use **crontab** and **at**.
Credit to @GoinOff for providing this link: [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restrict-at-cron-command-to-authorized-users/)